# How to pass list of hosts in ansible-playbook command?

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to run a playbook and provide the host directly from the command line because I frequently change the host IP and export it to the environment variable, called JUMPBOX_AZR. I have checked out Ansible documentation and for the ansible-playbook, the `-i` option it says:

> specify inventory host path or comma separated host list.
>   –inventory-file is deprecated

With "comma separated host list", I thought I could do something like this:

```
ansible-playbook -i "${JUMPBOX_AZR}" ~/terraform_azure/Ansible/prepare_acs.yml
```

But apparently not because I'm getting this error:

```
[WARNING]: Unable to parse /home/pedro/terraform_azure/Ansible/23.100.53.196 as an inventory source
```

What's the easiest way to supply a host to a playbook, if that host is in a local environment variable?

Comment: How are we supposed to know what is the value of `JUMPBOX_AZR` on your machine?

Comment: @techraf I believe it is quite easy to conclude that it would be the IP for the target box since it was the only env variable I mentioned in my post. But I have added that info for you.